# Потеря данных при отправке через сокет

Tags: python, android, kotlin, сокет

У меня есть клиентское приложение на android, написанное на Kotlin и сервер на Python
С клиента на сервер в отправляется запрос на получения файла (в моем случае изображение или json) и сервер его отправляет.
Проблема в том, что в подавляющем количестве случаев файл приходит не до конца, и я получаю недогруженную картинку или поврежденный json, а программа прекращает прием байт и продолжает выполняться дальше
Все, что смог найти в интернете - это разбить прием по мелким пакетам. Но это только частично увеличило кусок файла, что доходит. Без потерь отправить данные так и не получилось.

Подскажите, в чем проблема? Кажется, что упустил что-то до жути банальное
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Внизу часть кода, отвечающая за взаимодействие клиента и сервера:

Сервер (Python)

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0)
sock.bind(('',8080))
sock.listen(1)
conn,addr=sock.accept()
rec=str(conn.recv(1024),'utf-8')[2:]
answ=formed_answer(rec) #формирование ответа в формате строки json
conn.sendall((len(answ.encode('utf-8'))).to_bytes(4,byteorder='big'))
conn.sendall(answ.encode('utf-8'))
print('ready')
```

Клиент (Kotlin)

```
class Fight : Activity() {
    var adress ="192.168.1.109"
    val port = 8080

    @ExperimentalStdlibApi
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fight)
        thread { ClientHandler(adress, port).run() }
    }
}

class ClientHandler(adress: String, port: Int) : Runnable {
        val socket = Socket(adress, port)
        val dout = DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
        val inputStream = socket.getInputStream()

        @ExperimentalStdlibApi
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Throws(Exception::class)
        override fun run() {
            dout.writeUTF("give me answer:)")
            dout.flush()
            val size=ByteArray(4)
            try{
                        inputStream.read(size, 0,4)
            }catch (e:Exception) {
                        throw Exception("Невозможно получить данные: "+e.message);     }
            var l= BigInteger(size).toInt()
            var buf = ByteArray(1024)
            var answ=ByteArray(0)
            while(true){
             if(l>1024){ 
                        inputStream.read(buf,0,buf.size)
                        answ=answ+buf
                        }
             else {
                        inputStream.read(buf,0,l)
                        answ=answ+buf
                        break
                  }
            l-=1024
            }
            work_with_answer(answ)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упустили вы то, что при чтении из сокета `read` вполне может вернуть только часть посланных данных.

Нужно анализировать значение, которое `read` возвращает, это количество прочитанных байт, и на него уменьшать ожидаемое количество байт:

```
while (l > 0) {   
   num_read = inputStream.read(buf, 0, min(buf.size, l))
   if (num_read == -1) {  // end of stream
     break;
   }
   answ = answ + buf.copyOfRange(0, num_read)
   l -= num_read
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно, дело было лишь в этом. Помогло, спасибо!