# Java UDP сервер не принимает больше одного пакета

Tags: java, сокет

Есть клиент который отправляет картинку по частям в 2048 байтах. В ней 3 части.

Сервер принимает только первую часть и всё. Забавно что от перемены картинки берётся только первая часть.

По идее любой входящий пакет должен содержаться в inputPacket.getData(). Его содержимое меняется, но я не могу сложить его воедино.

Вот TCP нормально работает, а UDP нет. Читал что это возможно из-за брендмауэра.

Колхоз с Thread и while, чтобы работало без остановки в асинхронном режиме.

Где cv_img и т.д. это для того чтобы, сохранить полученные пакеты обратно в картинку.

```
public class Server_UDP {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket userSocket;
    private PrintWriter dataOutput;
    private BufferedReader dataInput;
    public BufferedImage cv_img;
    public byte[] byteArray = null;
    DatagramSocket aSocket = null;
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public void start(int port) throws IOException {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        Thread T = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                byte[] receivingDataBuffer = new byte[100000000];

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        DatagramPacket inputPacket = new DatagramPacket(receivingDataBuffer, receivingDataBuffer.length);
                        serverSocket.receive(inputPacket);
                        String modifiedSentence = new String(inputPacket.getData());
                        byteArray = inputPacket.getData();

                        System.out.println(modifiedSentence);
                    } catch (SocketException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Server_UDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Server_UDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));

                    cv_img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));
                    File outputfile = new File("G:\\Code_K\\dipolom\\image.png");
                    ImageIO.write(cv_img, "png", outputfile);

                    if (port == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server_UDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server_UDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
        T.start();
        //stop();
        System.out.println("STOP");
    }

    private void stop() throws IOException {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
        if (userSocket != null) {
            userSocket.close();
        }
        if (dataOutput != null) {
            dataOutput.close();
        }
        if (dataInput != null) {
            dataInput.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Server_UDP server = new Server_UDP();
        server.start(17777);
    }

}
```

Comment: Из буфера надо извлекать столько, сколько туда получено. А получено `inputPacket.getLength()` байт.
`String modifiedSentence = new String(inputPacket.getData(), 0, inputPacket.getLength());`
`cv_img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray, 0, inputPacket.getLength()));` Потом убедится, что клиент действительно что-то отправляет. Может ничего не отправляет, а Вы печатаете свой `byte[] receivingDataBuffer = new byte[100000000];` без изменений в нём.

Comment: @Sergey Вы правы. По отправлял кадры по проще. Ну там "123" "Хелло ворлд". 
Всё доходит.
Но картинка не сохраняется. Пишет что image == null, хотя все нужные данные там есть.

Comment: Значит не всё:) Но это уже вопрос о том, как правильно использовать imageio для сборки изображения из кусков.

Comment: @Sergey
Там картинка маленькая одним куском отправляется.
Вот такая строка должна её байтовое воплощение превращать в картинку.
cv_img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(modifiedSentence.getBytes()))

Comment: Так, а где код, который склеивает данные, которые читаются? Каждый вызов `receive` читает следующий кусок и вам нужно их объеденить в одно целое, знать когда все прислали и потому уже только использовать.  Почитайте тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1293159/218971 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1286291/218971 - там вопросы по питону, но причина проблемы у вас такая же - фрагментация, и способ решения такой же.

Comment: Приёмник UDP обрезает посылку, если она больше какой-то длины. Может дело в этом. Короткие сообщения принимает полностью, а от картинки только первые n байт (может она и маленькая для картинки, а для udp может быть большой поток байтов:). Точно не подскажу, где эту длину можно переопределить и чему она равна по умолчанию, но возможно методами DatagramSocket-а`setReceiveBufferSize` и `getReceiveBufferSize`.
Передающей системе надо передавать кусками не более этой длины. А принимающая должна уметь собирать всё из кусков.

Comment: Да я уже тут отправляю слово "стоп" и размерность в байтах картинки, чтобы как-то контролировать то что отправил и то что получил. В итоге у меня не совпадает кол-во отправленных и полученных.

Иногда отправлено больше, иногда меньше чем нужно, но никогда точное количество не совпадает.

Comment: Да я уже бросил эту идею т.к. не могу нормально реализовать контроль отправил\принял. Методом пердолинга обошёл её. Да и как-бы возможны дропы фреймов,а это не желательно.
Идея с самого начала была неудачной.